# py2exe looking for VC9.0

Tags: python, visual-c++, py2exe

I'm trying to use py2exe to compile a program according to this tutorial http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial and it seems to be looking for an older version of the microsoft redistributable libraries. The tutorial was written in March 2011, so I'm wondering if it may be out of date. I currently have Visual Studio 11.0 on my computer and py2exe is looking for 9.0.

I downloaded the Visual Studio 2008 redistributable package (vcredist_x86) and it doesn't seem to install anything new from what I can tell (at least not at the expected destination). I also tried replacing all of the path and filename references to 9.0 with the same for 11.0 and that didn't work either.

I'm using py2exe v0.6.9 with python v2.7.9 on windows 7. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem with **Python 2.7.8**

For py2exe v0.6.9, I installed **Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package (x86)**, from **[here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3387)**, which solved my problem.

**Edit:**

Try uninstalling the conflicting VC++ files and installing the forementioned one.

Or Alternatively use,

[cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) OR [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org), which work equivalently to py2exe.

Comment: I've actually tried that a few times and it doesn't seem to be installing any new files from what I can tell. Perhaps it sees that I have VC11.0 and quits. If that's the case then I suppose I would have to uninstall VC11.0.

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can try uninstalling VC11.0 or repairing your existing files.

Comment: Ok, I found the files as described in section 5.2.2 of the tutorial and followed the instructions given there, but now I am getting an error that says "error: can't copy 'c:\Windows\...\msvcm90.dll': doesn't exist or not a regular file. I checked and it does, in fact, exist.

Comment: The first link in your answer goes to a place to down load the **Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package (x86)**. Is that what you used or has the destination of the link changed? From what I've read elsewhere [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29) is the right one for that version of py2exe.

Comment: @martineau The Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package from my link worked for me and some others who were having the same problem...

Comment: I only asked because you say in your answer is that you installed **Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)** — I suggest you edit and fix it in that case.